# Styled Layer Descriptor importing problem

Tags: geoserver, sld, udig

I published a shapefile with GeoServer and changed that shapefile style using uDIG via WFS and then SLD file exported to some other place. My problem is while I'm trying to upload that SLD file in GeoServer I'm getting following error: `"Oops something went wrong"`...

Please help

Comment: is it a big file? sounds like a timout occured

Comment: No its not  a big file!!error like apache.Wicket.WicketRuntimeout..